# How to stop double click event firing from kendo ui grid header in angular 2+?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The double click event works fine on the row click but it also fires when the grid header is double clicked. Any idea how to stop this?

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true" (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)" (dblclick)="dblClickEvent($event)">
 <kendo-grid-column field="User" title="User" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

ts file for function :

```
onSelection(event): void {
    this.selectedItem = event.selectedRows[0].dataItem;
}

dblClickEvent($event) {
 // some functional logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mybe you can use event.currentTarget or event.target to distinguish which is clicked;

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="true" (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)" name='grid' (dblclick)="dblClickEvent($event)">
 <kendo-grid-column name='column' field="User" title="User" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

then

```js
if(event.target.name==='grid'){
...
}else if(event.target.name==='column'){

...
}
```